# Installing scrapy on ubuntu 14.04 fails with error in cryptography setup command Invalid environment marker

Tags: scrapy, ubuntu-14.04

I tried installing scrapy on another server. 
When I run `pip install scrapy`:

```
error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

any ideas please help

Python 2.7.6

I did

`sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`

and

`sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`

I did an `sudo apt-get update` before that too

Answer (score 3):

The same happens on debian 8. You can pin the `cryptography` library on version `2.0.3`, then retrying.

```
pip install cryptography==2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue and solved it via:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Apparently [the default version of setuptools and pip on 14.04 is insufficient](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/702) for the cryptography package.